# Chome doesn't work for localhost but firefox does

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, firefox, nginx-config

I have a issue where my webserver is nginx and i'm using firefox as my web browser. I have it pointing to my localhost and everything is working fine. It pulls up the website no problem. I decided to download chrome and also give it a try since I prefer it over FF.

It goes straight to the nginx homepage. When attempting to go to another url zeragames.localhost/user .. it will give a 404 not found.

I don't understand why it works perfectly fine in FF but with Chrome it cannot even find it. I know this obviously has to deal with some kind of DNS domain settings, but it has nothing to do with caching as I disabled all caching and also using incognito mode as well.

It just doesn't make any sense to me as to why it works in FF but with a fresh installation of chrome and it just can't find my server for the life of it.

nginx conf file:

```
server {
server_name zeragames.localhost;
root /var/www/html/zeragames/web; ## <-- Your only path reference.

location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

# Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
    allow 192.168.0.0/16;
    deny all;
}

location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
    return 403;
}

location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
    return 403;
}

# Block access to scripts in site files directory
location ~ ^/sites/[^/]+/files/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
}

# Allow "Well-Known URIs" as per RFC 5785
location ~* ^/.well-known/ {
    allow all;
}

# Block access to "hidden" files and directories whose names begin with a
# period. This includes directories used by version control systems such
# as Subversion or Git to store control files.
location ~ (^|/)\. {
    return 403;
}

location / {
    # try_files $uri @rewrite; # For Drupal <= 6
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string; # For Drupal >= 7
}

location @rewrite {
    #rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1; # For Drupal <= 6
    rewrite ^ /index.php; # For Drupal >= 7
}

# Don't allow direct access to PHP files in the vendor directory.
location ~ /vendor/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
location ~* \.(engine|inc|install|make|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|twig|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|yml)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|/(\.(?!well-known).*)|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|composer\.(json|lock)|web\.config$|/#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)$ {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}

# In Drupal 8, we must also match new paths where the '.php' appears in
# the middle, such as update.php/selection. The rule we use is strict,
# and only allows this pattern with the update.php front controller.
# This allows legacy path aliases in the form of
# blog/index.php/legacy-path to continue to route to Drupal nodes. If
# you do not have any paths like that, then you might prefer to use a
# laxer rule, such as:
#   location ~ \.php(/|$) {
# The laxer rule will continue to work if Drupal uses this new URL
# pattern with front controllers other than update.php in a future
# release.
location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
    # Ensure the php file exists. Mitigates CVE-2019-11043
    try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
    # Security note: If you're running a version of PHP older than the
    # latest 5.3, you should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini.
    # See http://serverfault.com/q/627903/94922 for details.
    include fastcgi_params;
    # Block httpoxy attacks. See https://httpoxy.org/.
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    # PHP 5 socket location.
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    # PHP 7 socket location.
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
}

# Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
# location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ { # For Drupal <= 6
location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ { # For Drupal >= 7
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

# Handle private files through Drupal. Private file's path can come
# with a language prefix.
location ~ ^(/[a-z\-]+)?/system/files/ { # For Drupal >= 7
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
}

# Enforce clean URLs
# Removes index.php from urls like www.example.com/index.php/my-page --> www.example.com/my-page
# Could be done with 301 for permanent or other redirect codes.
if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php/(.*)") {
    return 307 $1$2;
}
```

}

host file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   zeragames.localhost


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```